# How to render one single event over all sources in timeline view in Fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, timeline

Is here a option how to render one single event over all sources in timeline view in Fullcalendar v4? So it should look like this:

[image]

Only solution I figured out is add this kind of event always to the first source and set its height to 100% height of container. But it is a little dirty workaround, so I wonder if there is any more systematic solution.

Comment: You can associate an event with multiple resources - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events

Comment: Yes, that would be better, I guess. Many thanks.